# SES does not initialize properly when opening existing spreadsheet files

Tags: spreadsheet

When I attempt to open an existing SES (Simple Emacs Spreadsheet) file in GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601), the file comes up, but SES has not been properly initialized, even though the file extension is `.ses`, and there is an apparent (SES) mode-indicator in the emacs mode-line.  The header row doesn't show any column letters A, B, C, ..., and standard SES keys are *not* bound to their proper SES commands (e.g., `M-k` is bound to the default Emacs `kill-sentence` instead of the correct `ses-delete-column`, etc.).  The file incorrectly comes up in a full height (i.e., un-narrowed) buffer, but the SES command `ses-renarrow-buffer` is unavailable because its standard key `C-c C-n` is undefined.  In short, this version of SES can create spreadsheet files from scratch, but once the file is closed, SES will not properly re-open it.  Typing `M-x ses-mode` to a freshly opened existing SES file gives the error message "Invalid printer function".

Update -- Just before taking a suggestion of phils to try starting Emacs with the option -Q, I added three simple lines of code to my .emacs file which completely solved my immediate problem, but do not provide a basis for diagnosing the exact nature of the problem.  This new code loads a file defining a non-trivial printer function which is used to print most of the columns in my speadsheets, and adds that function to SES's list of "safe-functions".  Designating the function as "safe" avoids the need for a safety dialog that SES would otherwise insist on having at "find-file" time, in which the same question is asked for each column in my spreadsheets that use the function.  I strongly suspect that something about my impatient `y/n` responses to those questions led to the problem, but I haven't been able to reproduce the original problem in about 45 minutes of trying.  The mere occurrence of the dialog does not lead to the problem.  Given that the problem no longer stands in my way, I am unwilling to spend more time trying to find out exactly what triggered it in the first place, and why it was so persistent.

Comment: Does the problem happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?  If so, can you provide an example file, or some other recipe to reproduce the issue?

Comment: FYI I can't reproduce this issue in GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) with a very basic test file.

Comment: phils, I appreciate your efforts to help me, and hope that you didn't spend too much time on it.  I think your suggestion about Emacs -Q was a good one, though I didn't end up having to take it.  It did, however, help stimulate me to try the approach which actually worked.  -- Emacs-Lew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a satisfactory solution (of a sort) to the problem, without being able to exactly diagnose it, as explained in the above Update.  The code I added to my .emacs file (which was needed anyway in order to avoid a frustratingly repetitive safety dialogue) is as follows:

```el
;; load the code file defining the printer function num-to-cash  
(load-file "c:/ . . . /SES-functions.elc")  
;; add the SES printer function num-to-cash to the list safe-functions  
(setq safe-functions (cons 'num-to-cash (if (boundp 'safe-functions)  
                                            safe-functions  nil )))
```